# Whats the relation between AC power strip current rating and DC output current from the PSU connected on

Tags: power-supply, current, ratings

this is kind of a noob question:

I have a power strip (extension cord from my wall AC outlet) that is rated for 250V 10A.
Over this power strip i'm connecting a power supply that gives an output of 12V 20A.

What's the relation between the power strip current rating and the PSU one?. I mean, how could you state the needed value for the power strip based the PSU current rating?

It's enough to just calculate the power consumption in Watts on the PSU (Vout * Output current) being lower than the one rated for the power strip?

(I'm not connecting anything else besides the PSU on it).

Greetings.

Comment: Appliance AC current ratings are for breaker rating at max load and not what is actually flowing when lightly used.

Comment: You need to look at the PSU's *input* current rating since the input of the PSU is what is connected to the power strip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's enough to just calculate the power consumption in Watts on the PSU (Vout * Output current) being lower than the one rated for the power strip?

Yes. Power requirement of the PSU is \$ P = VI = 12 \cdot 20 \ = 240 \ \mathrm {W} \$.

On 230 V mains the current required by the PSU is \$ I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {240}{230} = 1 \ \mathrm {A} \$ (plus a little).

Your power strip is fine.

Comment: Cool, that I = P / V was the missing part in my thought.. With one side being AC and the other DC i tend to separate both parts as different things.. Thanks!

Comment: The quick way to think of it is that if you drop the voltage by a factor of 20 then the current goes up by a factor of 20. (Don't forget to factor in a bit for power supply losses.)